# FLuent nHibernate Linq Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I m facing issue to access the bridge table to get the values using nHibernate and LINQ.
I have 4 table, ROLES , MODULES , PERMISSIONS and the RoleModulePermission(bridge).

Roles contains ROLEID(pk) , ROLENAME 

Modules contains MODULEID(pk) , MODULENAME

Permission contains PERMISSIONID , PERMISSIONTYPE

RoleModulePermission contains ROLEID , MODULEID and PERMISSIONID


I want to get the Modules n Permission applied to the ROLES on the basis of ROLEID.

[image]

**Role Mapping**

```
  Table("tblRoles");
        Id(role => role.RoleID).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(role => role.RoleName).Not.Nullable();
        Map(role => role.IsActive).Not.Nullable();
        Map(role => role.Description).Not.Nullable();

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Users)
            .Table("tblUserInRoles")
            .ParentKeyColumn("RoleID")
            .ChildKeyColumn("UserID")
            .Not.LazyLoad();

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Modules)
            .Table("tblRolesPermission")
            .ParentKeyColumn("RoleID")
            .ChildKeyColumn("ModuleID")
            .Not.LazyLoad();

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Permissions)
            .Table("tblRolesPermission")
            .ParentKeyColumn("RoleID")
            .ChildKeyColumn("PermissionID")
            .Not.LazyLoad();
```

**Module Mapping**

```
 Table("tblAppModules");
        Id(mod => mod.ModuleID).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(mod => mod.ModuleName).Nullable();
        Map(mod => mod.CreationDate).Nullable();

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Roles)
            .Table("tblRolesPermission")
            .ParentKeyColumn("ModuleID")
            .ChildKeyColumn("RoleID")
            .Not.LazyLoad();
```

**Permission Mapping**

```
Table("tblPermission");
        Id(p => p.PermissionID).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(p => p.PermissionType).Not.Nullable();

        HasManyToMany(p => p.PermitRole)
            .Table("tblRolesPermission")
            .ParentKeyColumn("PermissionID")
            .ChildKeyColumn("RoleID")
            .Not.LazyLoad();
```

It seems that i did wrong in mapping ?

please do not assume 'AllowAccess' in tblRolesPermission
How to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: how does the classes you mapped look like?

Comment: mapping added to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapping for ternary associations in FluentNHibernate depends from specifics of your scenario and domain model.

Basically, if you are going to have the *many-to-many* relations everywhere (i.e. your Module can have multiple Permissions, Role can have multiple Permissions and Role can have multiple Modules), you'll need to have a separate entity for the relation, called i.e. `RoleModulePermission`. It will change your graph from triangle-like (3 classes) into a star-like (4 classes with common "root"). The new entity will have three *many-to-one* relations and `Role`, `Module` and `Permission` will have *one-to-many* relation to `RoleModulePermission`. Set up the cascades and you can try querying this model like any other:

```
session.Query<Permission>()
    .Where(x => x.RoleModules.Any(rm => rm.Module == module));
```

If your model is more restricted, i.e. you have some constraints, you can try to map it simpler using `AsTernaryAssociation` or `AsEntityMap`, which is pretty much the same. Then in your `Role`, `Module` and `Permission` classes you should have relation of type `IDictionary<TFrom, To>`. This can mean i.e. that Permission X maps Role Y to Module Z, but it means that within Permission X Role Y have no other Modules. Something like this in POCO class:

```
 public virtual IDictionary<Role, Module> RoleModules { get; set; }
```

and like this in mapping:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.RoleModules).Table("tblRolesPermissions").AsEntityMap();
```

does support it, but. You have to specify *one-to-many* or *many-to-many* relations at each side of the relation (in POCO's for `Roles`, `Modules` and `Permission`) and map each relation like that:

```
m.HasMany(x => x.RolesPermissionsModules).AsTernaryAssociation()
```

Querying using LINQ should then look somehow like this:

```
session.Query<Permission>()
    .Where(x => x.RoleModules[role] == module);
```